# How to change values of combobox in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs

I am using ext js to populate my two combo boxes. I want the value of combobox2 to change dynamically when an item is selected in combobox1. So far I have managed to get the contents that I want in the combobox2 which is in the required format.

For example:

This is what I am doing for this purpose:

```
 ddlLocation.on('select', function (box, record, index) {

    PageMethods.getAllBanksList(ddlLocation.getValue(), function (banks) {
        ddlBank.banksArray = banks;    //this is the assignment part
                                       //Bank returns the formatted string


    }, GenericErrorHandler);

});
```

this is my ddlBank combobox:

```
ddlBank = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Bank',
    labelStyle: 'width:130px',
    id: 'ddlBank',
    store: banksArray,
    mode: 'local',
    editable: false,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    value: banksArray[0][0]
});
```

It changes nothing on the assignment, Also it does not refreshes or even cleans out the values of the dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like what you are looking for.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?184207-Controlling-one-combobox-by-selection-of-another-combobox

Comment: Please don't link to examples without also giving an explanation. That link is now dead, so not very helpful.

Comment: simple quote based google search => https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?184207-Controlling-one-combobox-by-selection-of-another-combobox